# How Faucet Works without Gas fee?

Tags: solidity, ether, gas, evm, faucets

When we are requested for some ethers in Faucet we are not paid the gas, how can that method works?

if you can give me some example of code it'll makes me easier to understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you request ether you are not sending a transaction to the blockchain to mint that ether. When you are using the faucet then you are asking the owner of that faucet to send you some ether.

It is usually a normal program that run on the cloud and has a private key stored somewhere inside it. And the user send only a normal http request to that backend with his/her public key. The backend checks then if the sender is allowed or has permission to get ether (e.g. you can only request once a day) and then that program create and sign a transaction to send the ether to the public key of the sender.

> In other words, the owner of the faucet is paying for the transaction. He can do that because the ether on a testnet doesn't have a real value. –
> Stanislav Svědiroh

Comment: In other words, the owner of the faucet is paying for the transaction. He can do that because the ether on a testnet doesn't have a real value.

Comment: do you have any article or example of codes, how to transfer ether automatically in solidity?

Comment: what do you mean with automatically? a smart contract cannot run itself, someone should send a transaction and trigger it. And to send ether you don't need a smart contract , it is the native currency and it can be transferred with a normal transaction @Irwan

Comment: i meant when someone request the owner ether, the owner automatically approve and send it to the user

Comment: @Irwan it is a simple transaction , no need for a smart contract or solidity. The faucet's owner writes a normal application with javascript or java and use some of the web3 libraries to create and send the transaction https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--sending  http://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/transactions/transfer_eth/

Comment: if you want an ERC20 *mint* Faucet then you need a smart contract that can mint the tokens. like here https://cryptomarketpool.com/create-a-crypto-faucet-using-a-solidity-smart-contract/ . But as i said for ether you don't because you cannot mint it and it is the native currency so only a transfer transaction is possible

Comment: Alright @MajdTL, thank you for your answer and thanks for the sources of links. those looks good for me to read.